# How to prefix image is big how to be set small

Tags: flutter

How to prefix image is big how to be set small?

```dart
Container(
  height: 40,
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/search.png',width: 10,height: 10,),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          BorderSide()
      ),
      hintText: "serach here",
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Padding to add a pad around and to make an icon smaller.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.all(8.0),
  child: Image.asset('assets/images/search.png'),
)
```